# TypeError: Failed to convert elements of (None, -1, 3, 1) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a custom tensorflow layer which works fine by generating an output but it throws an error when used with the Keras functional API. Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

# --------- Custom Layer -------
def scaled_dot_product_attention(query, key, value, mask=None):
  key_dim = tf.cast(tf.shape(key)[-1], tf.float32)
  scaled_scores = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b=True) / np.sqrt(key_dim)

  if mask is not None:
    scaled_scores = tf.where(mask==0, -np.inf, scaled_scores)

  softmax = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
  weights = softmax(scaled_scores) 
  return tf.matmul(weights, value), weights

class MultiHeadSelfAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads):
    super(MultiHeadSelfAttention, self).__init__()
    self.d_model = d_model
    self.num_heads = num_heads

    self.d_head = self.d_model // self.num_heads

    self.wq = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.d_model)
    self.wk = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.d_model)
    self.wv = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.d_model)

    # Linear layer to generate the final output.
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.d_model)
  
  def split_heads(self, x):
    batch_size = x.shape[0]

    split_inputs = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, -1, self.num_heads, self.d_head))
    return tf.transpose(split_inputs, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])
  
  def merge_heads(self, x):
    batch_size = x.shape[0]

    merged_inputs = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])
    return tf.reshape(merged_inputs, (batch_size, -1, self.d_model))

  def call(self, q, k, v, mask):
    qs = self.wq(q)
    ks = self.wk(k)
    vs = self.wv(v)

    qs = self.split_heads(qs)
    ks = self.split_heads(ks)
    vs = self.split_heads(vs)

    output, attn_weights = scaled_dot_product_attention(qs, ks, vs, mask)
    output = self.merge_heads(output)

    return self.dense(output)

# ----- Testing with simulated data ------- 
x = np.random.rand(1,2,3)
values_emb = MultiHeadSelfAttention(3, 3)(x,x,x, mask = None)
print(values_emb)
```

This generates the following output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 0.50706375 -0.3537539  -0.23286441]
  [ 0.5081617  -0.3548487  -0.23382033]]], shape=(1, 2, 3), dtype=float32)
```

But when I use it in the Keras functional API it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```py
x = Input(shape=(2,3))
values_emb = MultiHeadSelfAttention(3, 3)(x,x,x, mask = None)
model = Model(x, values_emb)
model.summary()
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert elements of (None, -1, 3, 1) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi Amin! I am able to get results in 2.9.2 . Please make sure you are not mixing tensorflow.keras and keras api. You have to either use keras api or tensorflow.keras api. Attached [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/mohantym/ad92023909902d3ec414a2a012a0b723/stack_75075099.ipynb) for reference.